# combining bottom navigation with bottom sheet

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, bottom-sheet

Android uses specific shape on top of expandable bottom sheet, is this a normal bottom sheet or it is a different android component?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHfSH.jpg

Comment: It's important that questions have an specific scope, which will help people to give accurate answers. You may split the question into two different questions: one regarding the shape of the bottom nav, and other regarding the best practices

Comment: thanks for advise, I ask the questions separately.